# How to merge two SQL select statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I wrote a query in SQL with two select statement, but I get an error as the result.

My query is :

```
 SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNum',
     Employment_Tests_Courses.Title as [Course],
     Employment_Tests_Courses.ID,
     Employment_Tests_Courses.TID,
     (SELECT T1.Title as [Title Exam] 
      FROM Employment_Tests_Title T1  
      INNER JOIN Employment_Tests_Courses T2 ON T1.ID = T2.TID),
     (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Employment_Tests_Questions 
      WHERE Employment_Tests_Courses.ID = Employment_Tests_Questions.CID) as [Question Count]
 FROM
     Employment_Tests_Courses
```

but in the output I get this error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

In middle select's statement i get back 42 rows and all rows count is same.

The tables view is:

`Employment_Tests_Title`

```
ID     Title
```

`Employment_Tests_Courses`

```
ID     TID (Employment_Tests_Title ID)     Title
```

`Employment_Tests_Questions`

```
ID      TID (Employment_Tests_Title ID)     Title      CID (Employment_Tests_Course ID)
```

Please help me how can I write this query.

Thanks

Comment: Also we need Data - - table's and columns. The chances are the error is 100% kosher and is due to your first subquery returning multiple rows. However what you've given us will in no way aid anyone to fully answer the question to your satisfaction. In order to answer you absolutely have to tell us what the expected results are, and for that we need tables and data. As it stands your question stands a high risk of being put on hold. Consider using a Sql Fiddle to set something up: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What do you want to express? Please apply Occam's razor and use short identifiers. Why would you expect a single value in your subselect and why want you to use it in the selection part? Maybe the solution is a `group by` clause, but without understanding, what you want to get, we have no chance to help you.

Comment: Query for  [Question Count] is returning multiple rows. Run that separately and u would identify the problem.

Comment: when i run separately the middle select statements, thats run very well and each return 42 rows but when i merge them i receive error

Comment: So, you just answered your own question. The Middle query returns 42 rows but your outer query is expecting only 1. You can't merge them that way. If you wish to connect the results, use a Join. This is why you need to tell us what the expected results are.

Comment: how can i merge this statements with the Join?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error is in this statement:

```
(SELECT T1.Title as [Title Exam] 
  FROM Employment_Tests_Title T1  
  INNER JOIN Employment_Tests_Courses T2 ON T1.ID = T2.TID),
```

The reason is that this returns more than 1 result according to your error (without data it's hard to check, but i'm pretty sure this is the case).

Comment: yes when i remove this statement the query run fine and when this statement runs separately in other new query this run fine but i need way to merge this statements

Comment: you need to make sure that the result of this query will return only 1 value. probably, you need to add WHERE clause for it to know which title to return. ALTERNATIVELY, you can take this sub-query out and include it in the join... (probably easier).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNum',
    Courses.Title as [Course],
    Courses.ID, 
    Courses.TID,
    T1.Title as [Title Exam],
    (select count(*)
         From Employment_Tests_Questions Q
         where Courses.ID = Q.CID) 
    as [Question Count]
FROM Employment_Tests_Courses Courses
JOIN Employment_Tests_Title T1
ON T1.ID=Courses.TID
```

Comment: perfect code.. this run perfectly.. thanks a lot dev.null